# 'exim -d' - where does stderr go?

Tags: debugging, redirect, stderr, tee, exim

I am using exim 4.92.3 on a CentOS 7.8.
I wanted to capture all the output from the command used for testing aliases resolution (`exim -d -bt adres@domain |& tee exim-test.out`), but only stdout was displayed on the terminal and written to the file. When I split outputs with `exim [...] 1>1.out 2>2.out` the streams are separated and recorded as expected. How to send both stdout and stderr from exim to one file, and why it is behaving like this?
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

> why it is behaving like this?

This can only be answered if you specify ***it***, i. e. which shell is used. It may be that ***it*** doesn't offer `|&`.

> How to send both stdout and stderr from exim to one file

`2>&1` will work, i. e. `exim -d -bt adres@domain 2>&1 | tee exim-test.out`.

> tee is changing the order of lines

You may be able to avoid the perceived reordering by prepending `stdbuf -oL` to the `exim` command.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
It is GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Comment: ... and the tee - (GNU coreutils) 8.22 (both bash and tee installed from the CentOS 7 updates repo).

And yes, you are right, the command given by you works, **except**... the **tee is changing the order of lines** (compared to invocation without redirection). This was the reason I was confused and thought that there was no stderr in the output when piped through tee. It had not occurred to me before to check the number of lines in both outputs.

Comment: I added a suggestion to avoid the changing.